# What are some good resources for learning how to implement Scheme Macros?

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, macros, scheme

I've written a Scheme-ish language compiler/vm in JavaScript. http://github.com/z5h/zb-lisp
Dybvig's "Three Scheme Implementations" paper (available on my github) was hugely important in getting stuff like tail-call-optimization, call/cc and other things working.

I'm thinking about adding some type of macro support. And wondering if there are similarly awesome references for implementing macro systems.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lisp in Small Pieces](http://pagesperso-systeme.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/LiSP.html) is what you need.

Comment: +1. Looks good. Just ordered it off Amazon. If it is what I'm looking for, I'll accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @z5h The book explains implementation of Scheme interpreters and compilers. Especially see chapter 9, where the implementation of a macro system is explained.

Comment: It just arrived. Wow, it's going to take me a year to get through it!